# SQL/access question: Do not append that student-term record if the student AND the term already exist!

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have another SQL/access 2007 question that seems really basic but I'm not sure how to Google for it.

I have this table STUDENT-TERMS with the following fields:

StudentTermID

StudentID (links to STUDENT table)

TermID (links to TERMS table)

TermGPA (this is the nugget of info that needs to be recorded)

STUDENT table looks like this:

StudentID

Name

TERMS table looks like this:

TermID

Start date

End date

I have a document with all of the info that gets uploaded into the Access doc. This document that I get has the same student and term IDs as exist in the database.

Then I can run an append query to get the data into the STUDENT-TERMS table. Which is fine.

How do I write the query such that there is only one record of each term for each student?
So for example I have this data in the table right now:

StudentTerm ID: 5

StudentID: Tara

TermID: 1011Autumn

TermGPA: 3.8

When I upload and append a new document, it might still contain that information about Tara and I want the db to say "Hey, we already have that, skip it" as it does the appending. How do I indicate that?

HERE IS THE CONCLUSION/ANSWER/RESOLUTION:
Thanks for your help everyone. This is what I wound up doing:

1. I made a new field in the table called StudentTerm which contains a concatenation of the StudentID and the Term (like so: Tara1011Autumn). This field is indexed with no duplicates.
2. The query that performs the appending looks like this:

INSERT INTO StudentTerms ( StudentID, TermID, GPA, StudentTerm )
SELECT 
Upload_Students.StudentID, Upload_Students.TermID, Upload_Students.GPA, 
[Upload_Students]![StudentID] & [Upload_Students]![TermID] AS Expr1
FROM Students INNER JOIN Upload_Students ON Students.StudentID = Upload_Students.StudentID;

This query attempts to fill the StudentTerm field with Tara1011Autumn. If that string already exists in the table, it won't append the record.

Comment: Pleas describe the table student and terms

Comment: Does your upload file have StudentID's in it?

Comment: Why did you concatenate the fields instead of just creating a compound index, as was suggested in the answer you accepted? From my point of view, what you ended up doing is a really terrible idea for any number of reasons.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the answer.

Comment: But now you have to populate that field for all your new records and if the constituent values change, you'll have to update it. The compound index on two fields is the correct answer (the one you accepted). If you don't understand what that means, then ask and all will be explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique index on the [student-terms] table, with the StudentID and StudentTermID fields in the index.

Then, when you run the append query Access will tell you "# records couldn't be added due to key violations", before asking you if you want to continue. If you hit Yes in that dialog box, then all the non-violating records will be appended, and the offending records will be saved into a different table.

There are other options available in the DoCmd.RunQuery action if you're doing this from VBA to automate this.

Comment: If the business requirement is that the a studentTerm record is unique, then use a unique index to enforce it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are doing a SQL based append query, you can use a NOT EXISTS clause.

**Note**
*I'm assuming here that you can have multiple STUDENT-TERMS records for the same student if the StudentTermID is different.*

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT-TERMS
          ( StudentTermId
          , StudentId
          , TermID
          , TermGPA )
     SELECT 5
          , 'Tara'
          , '1011Autumn'
          , 3.8
      WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT * FROM STUDENT-TERMS WHERE StudentID = 'Tara'
                                           AND StudentTermId = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Assumption database is in the 3NF *

```
SELECT st.StudentId, s.StudentName, t.TermId, t.TermName, st.TermGPA
FROM STUDENTS_TERMS st
INNER JOIN STUDENT s ON st.StudentID = s.StudentId
INNER JOIN TERMS t on st.TERMS = t.TermId
WHERE st.StudentID = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on dcp's answer but adjusted for Access

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT-TERMS
      ( StudentTermId
      , StudentId
      , TermID
      , TermGPA )
 SELECT DISTINCT 5
      , 'Tara'
      , '1011Autumn'
      , 3.8
  FROM STUDENT-TERMS
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM STUDENT-TERMS WHERE StudentID = 'Tara'
                                       AND StudentTermId = 5)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this insert zero rows if STUDENT-TERMS is empty?

Comment: How would this look if I didn't know which records might duplicate, I just want to prevent any possible duplicates? In other words, how would you write this replacing the specific "Tara" and "5" with variables?

Comment: @Justin K Yes. However, a from table is needed in Access, but it can be any table in this case, even MsysObjects, a system table.

Comment: If you want to be sure of unique values, it is generally best to use a unique index.

Comment: Where did you see the variables coming from? Did you want parameters?

Comment: I don't know, just some way to not have to specify in the code which values will be duplicated. I won't know in advance which values should be excluded.

Comment: You are running the SQL in VBA? If so, you can use a parameter query or use variables with an SQL string, though you may have to watch for injection attack, depending on your environment.